# Using Windows functions in SQL, how to find the student with the highest average of three subjects?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Student Id | marks
101        | 93,63,74,
102        | 63,66,34,
103        | 93,64,54,
104        | 43,93,34,
105        | 95,83,54,
```

I have this data available in a table "Students" with two columns " student_ID" and "marks".

the marks are for 3 subjects maths, english and science but are in Comma within a single table. How to use windows functions to find the student with highest average among all?

Comment: Store your data correctly!  on't store multiple values in a string!  You should also edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: version 8.0.15.

Comment: required result is the id of the student who has the highest average in maths, english and science

Comment: Why the poor database design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to split your list of marks into individual marks, then take `AVG` of those marks using a window function, order by that value descending and take only the first result:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT student_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(marks, ',', 1) AS mark,
         SUBSTRING(marks, LOCATE(',', marks) + 1) AS balance
  FROM data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT student_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(balance, ',', 1),
         SUBSTRING(balance, LOCATE(',', balance) + 1)
  FROM CTE
  WHERE LOCATE(',', balance) > 0
)
SELECT student_id, 
       ROUND(AVG(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id), 2) AS avg_mark
FROM CTE
ORDER BY avg_mark DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
student_id  avg_mark
105         77.33
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bo5srCB8ZkyM6Qx5VKDgq1/0)

Comment: You could just use a second CTE e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bo5srCB8ZkyM6Qx5VKDgq1/2

Comment: if i remove the limit 1, i get bit peculier response.

Comment: You will get multiple rows if you remove the `limit`. It's there so that you *only* get the `student_id` with the highest average.

Comment: I think you'd be better served with straight aggregation rather than window functions: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bo5srCB8ZkyM6Qx5VKDgq1/3

Comment: I was trying to see the result if limit not applied. I was not going to put the final code without limit

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data using `union all`.  Then to get the maximum `mark` you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select m.*
from ((select student_id, substring_index(marks, ',', 1) + 0 as mark, 'maths' as subject
       from marks
      ) union all
      (select student_id, substring_index(substring_index(marks, ',', 2), ',', -1) + 0 as mark, 'english'
       from marks
      ) union all
      (select student_id, substring_index(marks, ',', -1) + 0 as mark, 'science'
       from marks
      )
     ) m
order by mark desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: just to clarify, the result needs to be a student who scored highest after averaging the 3 subject marks